# How to upload a file(image) with Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, replicate

I am trying to:

1. Upload a picture to a Next.js app
2. Run it through `cjwbw/real-esrgan:d0ee3d708c9b911f122a4ad90046c5d26a0293b99476d697f6bb7f2e251ce2d4`
3. Then return the enhanced image

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

from what I am able to understand you are trying to use **replicate** model for high-resolution images.

To achieve the steps you mentioned you'll need to set up a server in your Next.js app to handle the image processing using Docker or if you want to use Node.js try going through these [docs](https://replicate.com/cjwbw/real-esrgan/api)

> we will first upload image from Next js application then set up a
> backend server using Node.js within your Next.js app. This server will
> handle image processing using the Docker image.
>
> Then we will use the cjwbw/real-esrgan Docker image to process the
> uploaded image and enhance it.

**Step 1:**
setup next js application and handle image upload.

```js
// pages/index.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const ImageUploader = () => {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

  const handleImageUpload = async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/enhance-image', formData);
      // Handle the enhanced image response here
      console.log('Enhanced image:', response.data);
      // Update state or display the enhanced image
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error enhancing image:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleImageUpload} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageUploader;
```

****Step 2:**
To process the image and return it as a response**

```js
// pages/api/enhance-image.js

import { execSync } from 'child_process';

export default async (req, res) => {
  const imagePath = req.body.image.path; // Assuming the image is uploaded to a temporary directory
  const enhancedImagePath = 'path/to/save/enhanced-image.jpg'; // Provide a path to save the enhanced image

  // Run the image enhancement using Docker
  execSync(
    `docker run -v ${imagePath}:/input -v ${enhancedImagePath}:/output cjwbw/real-esrgan:d0ee3d708c9b911f122a4ad90046c5d26a0293b99476d697f6bb7f2e251ce2d4`
  );

  // Return the path to the enhanced image
  res.status(200).json({ enhancedImagePath });
};
```

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

Use a file input and send the output value to the esrgan api and retrieve the enhanced image from the api response

```
<input
  type="file"
  id="input"
  accept="image/*" />
```

Select the image using the input, and now you can send the selected image

```
const selectedImage = document.getElementById("input").files[0]
```

Or you can use a ref instead of the id by using the `useRef` react hook and assigning a ref to the input and get the file from the input ref

```
const inputRef = useRef(null)
<input
  type="file"
  ref={inputRef}
  accept="image/*" />
const selectedImage = inputRef.current.files[0]
```

....send the selected image to the api

Comment: Hello I am having problems with implementing your solution into my code Do you have Discord so I can ask you there.Because the this chat is limited

Comment: Can you share the problem here as I'm not active on discord

Comment: OK.My code is in my last stack overflow question

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiIpW.png)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  Input,
  InputProps,
  Progress,
} from "@nextui-org/react";
import { IoCloseSharp } from "react-icons/io5";
import { TbUpload } from "react-icons/tb";
import StyledImage from "./StyledImage";

interface FileUploadProps extends InputProps {
  onFileUpload: (files: FileList) => void;
}

const FileUpload: React.FC<FileUploadProps> = ({ onFileUpload, ...props }) => {
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [filePreviews, setFilePreviews] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleDragEnter = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDragging(true);
  };

  const handleDragLeave = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDragging(false);
  };

  const handleDrop = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDragging(false);

    const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
      uploadFiles(files);
      previewFiles(files);
    }
  };

  const handleFileInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const files = e.target.files;
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      uploadFiles(files);
      previewFiles(files);
    }
  };

  const uploadFiles = (files: FileList) => {
    // Simulate file upload progress for each file
    Array.from(files).forEach((file, index) => {
      const totalSize = file.size;
      const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunks for demonstration
      let uploaded = 0;

      const uploadInterval = setInterval(() => {
        uploaded += chunkSize;
        const progress = (uploaded / totalSize) * 100;

        setUploadProgress(progress);

        if (progress >= 100) {
          clearInterval(uploadInterval);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setUploadProgress(null);
            onFileUpload(files);
          }, 500); // Delay for visual feedback
        }
      }, 500); // Simulated 500ms delay per chunk
    });
  };

  const previewFiles = (files: FileList) => {
    const previews: string[] = [];
    Array.from(files).forEach((file) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        previews.push(reader.result as string);
        setFilePreviews([...previews]);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  };

  const handleDeletePreview = (index: number) => {
    const updatedPreviews = [...filePreviews];
    updatedPreviews.splice(index, 1);
    setFilePreviews(updatedPreviews);
  };

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardBody>
        <div
          className={`relative border-2 border-dashed border-gray-400 p-4 text-center ${
            isDragging ? "bg-gray-100" : ""
          }`}
          onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
          onDragOver={handleDragEnter}
          onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
          onDrop={handleDrop}
        >
          <Input
            id="file-input"
            type="file"
            {...props}
            onChange={handleFileInputChange}
            className="hidden"
            multiple // Enable multiple file selection
          />
          <label
            htmlFor={props.id || "file-input"}
            className="cursor-pointer text-gray-500 w-full h-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center"
          >
            {/* Content inside label */}
            <p className="">Drag & drop your files here</p>
            <TbUpload className="text-6xl my-2" />
            <span className="">Browse for files</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap gap-4">
          {filePreviews.map((preview, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="mt-3 relative">
              <StyledImage
                src={preview}
                alt={`File Preview ${index + 1}`}
                className="w-[100px] h-[100px]"
                width={100}
                height={100}
              />
              <Button
                isIconOnly
                color="danger"
                size="sm"
                onClick={() => handleDeletePreview(index)}
                className="absolute top-0 right-0 p-2 text-white rounded-full z-10"
              >
                <IoCloseSharp className="text-5xl" />
              </Button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        {uploadProgress !== null && (
          <Progress
            value={uploadProgress}
            maxValue={100}
            className="mt-3"
            color="primary"
          />
        )}
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};

// Usage
const StyledFileUpload: React.FC = () => {
  const handleFileUpload = (files: FileList) => {
    // Handle the uploaded files here
    console.log("Uploaded files:", files);
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <FileUpload onFileUpload={handleFileUpload} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default StyledFileUpload;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).